# GLSL: smooth double in

Tags: double, glsl

I'd like to do this:

```c
layout(location = 0) in dvec2 c;
```

But apparently I can't:

```
$ glslc mandlebrot.frag
mandlebrot.frag:7: error: 'double' : must be qualified as flat in
```

However, I require this input be interpolated, not [flat](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Nicol's answer appears to be technically correct, there is a work-around. A `float` value has more than enough precision to target a pixel on a screen; it just may not have enough to target a position within the "world" (in this case, a fractal).

The solution then is to use a uniform buffer to pass world coordinates for some fixed point relative to the screen (in this case, the centre), then compute pixel coordinates from that:

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform Locals {
    dvec2 centre;
    dvec2 scale;
};

void main() {
    dvec2 c = centre + dvec2(cf) * scale;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nope](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#input-variables):

> Fragment shader inputs that are, or contain, integral or double-precision floating-point types must be qualified with the interpolation qualifier `flat`.

So you're going to have to make them `float`s.